# Regex: combines not equals, not contained in and match up until

Tags: regex

I need a regex that:

- won't match if the string is equal to any of a series of strings
- won't match if any of another series of sub-strings is contained anywhere within
- and will match only up until any of a set of certain delimiter characters.

I've got the first two requirements, but can't figure out how to add in the last part:

```
^(?:((?!^fill$)(?!^style$)(?!->)[^;:]))*$
```

Will not match 'fill' or 'style' (but will match 'fills' or 'astyle').
Will not match if '->' is anywhere inside. (e.g. don't match 'a->b')
However a : or a ; will cause no match, rather than matching up until the first occurrence of either of those characters.
e.g.

```
Will:
```

should return 'Will' but currently returns nothing.

Comment: Maybe `^(?!(?:fill|style)$|.*->)[^;:]*$`?

Comment: Thank you I should clarify that the sub-strings that cannot be anywhere is also a series e.g. '->' '<->' <-' '--' etc. Could you suggestion be extended to accommodate an extensible series? I will try to edit my question for clarity

Comment: `^(?!(?:fill|style)$|.*(?:-[>-]|<-))[^;:]*$`

Comment: Thank you. Returns no match for 'Will:' or 'bob:'. I would like it to return 'Will' or 'bob' i.e. match up until the first occurrence of any of the delimiter characters.

Comment: Then use `^(?!(?:fill|style)$|.*(?:-[>-]|<-))[^;:]+`, https://regex101.com/r/KjT1fF/4

Comment: Thank you again! I'm clarifying my requirement as you're answering! The above works but 'fill:' ('fill' being one of the banned strings) now matches and returns 'fill'. I could add into the negative lookahead e.g. `^(?!(?:fill|style|fill:|style:|fill;|style;)$|.*(?:-[>-]|<-))[^;:]+` but is there another more elegant way?

Comment: `fill|style|fill:|style:|fill;|style;` => `fill[:;]|style[;:]` or  `(?:fill|style)[;:]`

Comment: It is not any different from the solution in the answer, just keep extending it as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!(?:fill|style)$|.*(?:-[>-]|<-))[^;:]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjT1fF/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:fill|style)$|.*(?:-[>-]|<-))` - immediately to the right, there can't be:

  - `(?:fill|style)$` - `fill` or `style` (followed by the end of string)
  - `|` - or
  - `.*(?:-[>-]|<-)` - after any zero or more chars as many as possible, `--`, `->`, `<-` (note the `<->` alternative is missing since `<-` covers it)
- `[^;:]+` - any zero or more chars other than `;` and `:` as many as possible

Comment: This works - thank you. See comments above for some fringe cases